# Having incremental order ids for tr in tables after deleting rows too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have table with following format

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="help[0].id" />
      </td>
      <td> <span class="tr-close">X</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="help[1].id" />
      </td>
      <td> <span class="tr-close">X</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="help[2].id" />
      </td>
      <td> <span class="tr-close">X</span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I have Add button which will add row to the end of table. On clicking X icon I am deleting the entire row. Suppose if I delete row with name help[1].id, Now if I again add the new row, it should have help[1].id..So, on each addition/deletion the name should have differenct incrementatal non repeating numbers like id's 0,1,2,3....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the row, you can loop through each hidden field to update the name attribute. You can use `.each()` for looping. use `.attr()` method to update the name attribute

```
$(".tr-close").click(function(){
 $(this).parents("tr").remove();
 $("input[type=hidden]").each(function(i){

$(this).attr("name","help["+i+"]");
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUjmh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
//In order to have the dynamically created rows to have the

//delete function also you can use you on() like this    

$('table').on('click', '.tr-close', function(){

  $(this).parents('tr').remove();

});

// the #add refers to the add button you use

$('#add').click(function(){

  var counter = 0;

  $('table')

  .append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name=""/></td><td> <span class="tr-close">X</span></td></tr>');

  $('tr').each(function(){

    $(this).find('input').prop('name', 'help[' + counter + '].id');

    counter++;

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a "Heap" data structure to maintain the smallest number of your deleted index. Pick from the Heap when you add a new row.

```
RemoveRow -> 
    Insert index to Heap

AddRow ->
    if Heap is empty:
        Index = Rows.length
    else:
        Index = top of heap
        remove top of heap
```